# Error on Javascript on Multiplying Decimals 16.08 * 100

Tags: javascript, math

Why the result of this data is doesn't give the exact value expected by a human brain or expected output of a person to appear

```
16.08 * 100 = 1607.9999999999998;
```

When i tried it to the console developer of the chrome browser;

and i tried using

```
console.log(16.08*100); gives 1607.9999999999998
```

Supposedly the answer that i should be seeing is

```
16.08 * 100 = 1608;
```

will you please help me with these. or any explanations

Comment: Floating point numbers are susceptible rounding errors. This is normal behavior. This is also why you should never strictly compare floating point numbers in Javascript, but should compare the difference of two floating point numbers relative to some threshold, like `abs(a-b) > .01` as opposed to `a == b`.

Comment: @AlexLuecke can you give me example on this "abs(a-b) > .01 as opposed to a == b"

Answer (score 1):

use [***.toFixed(n)***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method of javascript.

```
console.log((16.08 * 100).toFixed());
```

Comment: Isn't that what is should be?